# List packages coming from a specific Codename or Suite (apt based systems)

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

I already know how to list every package from a given "origin", thanks to `aptitude` [awesome search features](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html):

```
aptitude search "?origin(My Backports)"
```

However, in the repository `Release` file, there is not only `Origin:`, but also `Codename:` and `Suite:`. For example, the current [Debian Release file](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release) has:

```
Origin: Debian
Suite: stable
Codename: wheezy
```

**How can I search for those `Codename` and `Suite`?**

Comment: @Braiam why don't you want the word "Debian" to appear in the question title? I know Ubuntu is concerned as well, but not mentioning the context is pretty confusing here.

Comment: Because neither Debian nor Ubuntu is really relevant here. You want to know how to list the packages using a specific Codename/Suite. That's only relevant to APT. The fact that the names change between Debian or Ubuntu is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, is not possible with the Suite nor Codename. The most near you will get is using `?archive`.

```
aptitude search '?archive(stable)'
```

I'm not sure if it's a limitation of the ABI, but aptitude does not provide searchs by neither Suite or Codename.

Answer (score 1):

In recent `apt` versions you can use the [`apt-patterns`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-patterns) like this:

```
apt list '?archive(testing)'
```

Comment: And what about Codename and Suite? (this is my question)

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant to use `?archive()` instead of `?section()`. I've updated my answer.
Edit: actually, I've realized my answer isn't really that different from @Braiam's. I don't know what was going on in my head when I left it :) At least we now know that you don't need `aptitude` to do it